# Gradient Background on Flutter AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, appbar, flutter-widget

How do I set the `backgroundColor` of theAppBar to a gradient?

Comment: for others https://pub.dev/packages/gradientscaffoldwidget

Comment: you can use flexibleSpace property from AppBar to achieve gradient background.

Comment: Check this out: https://hackernoon.com/flutter-gradient-app-bar-jm8a32fu

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I don't believe you can pass a gradient to an AppBar as it expects a Color rather than a gradient.

You can, however, create your own widget that mimics an AppBar except by using a gradient. 
Take a look at this example that I've pieced together from the [Planets-Flutter tutorial](https://sergiandreplace.com/planets-flutter-from-design-to-app/) along with the code below it.

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children : <Widget>[GradientAppBar("Custom Gradient App Bar"), Container()],);
  }
}


class GradientAppBar extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;
  final double barHeight = 50.0;

  GradientAppBar(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double statusbarHeight = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .padding
        .top;

    return new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusbarHeight),
      height: statusbarHeight + barHeight,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
            begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: can I add action button in the custom-made AppBar

Comment: won't this be problematic since all the other default behaviours of appbar will need to be rewritten? Take the back button for navigation for example. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: It seems like using this library is the ultimate solution https://github.com/joostlek/GradientAppBar

Comment: How can we hide black transparent layer from status bar as well?

Comment: It is possible to set GradientAppBar directly to appBar using PreferredSizeWidget.

Comment: Tks so much, bro!!!! U just save my time <3

Comment: This is not a AppBar. This one is only a Container with gradient background. Real AppBars can open a drawer, default back button functionality , flexible space and bottom for work with TabBar widget ect.

Answer (score 78):

This should work flawlessly:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
    flexibleSpace: Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: <Color>[Colors.black, Colors.blue]),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because it doesn't override widget locations of default appbar. With this solution, your existing action buttons and back buttons will continue working. Really flawless! Thanks!

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thx.

Answer (score 17):

**AppBar does not have that feature by default**. But you can make an AppBar like widget which will have a gradient background as follow:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new PreferredSize(
        child: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top
          ),
          child: new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 30.0,
              top: 20.0,
              bottom: 20.0
            ),
            child: new Text(
              'Arnold Parge',
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.white
              ),
            ),
          ),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            gradient: new LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.red,
                Colors.yellow
              ]
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              new BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey[500],
                blurRadius: 20.0,
                spreadRadius: 1.0,
              )
            ]
          ),
        ),
        preferredSize: new Size(
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          150.0
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('Hello'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here `boxShadow` will give elevated feel.

Comment: This answer is nice and I upvoted it, however, it DOESN"T support Drawers and other native AppBar functionalities, And this library is GREAT https://github.com/joostlek/GradientAppBar

Comment: It can be done using Appbar only. Follow this link. https://hackernoon.com/flutter-gradient-app-bar-jm8a32fu

Comment: This is not a AppBar. This one is only a Container with gradient background. Real AppBars can work with drawer api, navigation api (for default pop) , flexible space and bottom for work with TabBar widget ect.

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap AppBar in the Widgets Material > Container with grandient, so you can keep the original AppBar's attributes. here is my implementation with necesary attributes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    this.title,
    this.leading,
    this.actions,
    this.elevation = 2.0,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Widget? title;
  final Widget? leading;
  final double elevation;
  final List<Widget>? actions;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: elevation,
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: RadialGradient(
            radius: 2.5,
            stops: [
              0.0,
              0.27,
              1.0,
            ],
            colors: [
              Color(0XFFB71731),
              Color(0XFFB71731),
              Color(0XFFA5004E),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: leading,
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: title,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          actions: actions,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

then, just use it wherever you want

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
            appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
            body: Center(child:Text("My App gradient"),
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can decorate using `flexibleSpace`**

```
appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(widget.title),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: <Color>[
              Colors.red,
              Colors.blue
            ])          
         ),        
     ),      
 ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the background and shadow colors to Colors.transparent in a standard AppBar, then wrap a Container(...) around it, using BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(...)), and bob is, of course, your uncle.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pga_app/core/colors.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const CustomAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme thm = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Container(
      child: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: const Text(
          "My Cool App",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.menu, size: 36, color: COLOR_BUTTON_WHITE),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [0.0, 1.0],
          colors: [
            COLOR_PANEL_DARK_BLUE,
            COLOR_PANEL_BLUE,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(900, 56);
}
```

Forgive my use of undefined (in this post) constants; this was pulled from a production app and the names were changed to protect the innocent.

[image: Screen cap showing gradient in app bar]

Comment: The other answer didn't work for some reason. This did! Thank you so much I think this is the simplest and most intuitive. Great job, thanks for helping. I would've posted this but I noticed you did first so I gave an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

@Riki137 answer work like charm.
Here's another approach if anyone wanna give it a try.

```
   _appBar = AppBar();
   return PreferredSize(
     child: ShaderMask(
         child: _appBar,
        shaderCallback: (rect) {
           return ui.Gradient.linear(rect.centerLeft, rect.centerRight,
               [Colors.black, Colors.grey]);
         }),
     preferredSize: _appBar.preferredSize,
  );
```